# Integrating Libcamera Library with Raspberry Pi 5 for Global Shutter Camera in C++

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project with the Raspberry Pi 5 where I've successfully utilized a global shutter camera via the Camera2 API in Python3. However, I'm now looking to transition this setup to a C++ environment, specifically focusing on integrating the Libcamera library for enhanced control and functionality. While I have a basic understanding of Python, I'm quite new to C++ and even more so to managing projects with CMake on the Raspberry Pi.

I found the Libcamera library on GitHub (Libcamera GitHub) and believe it's the right tool for my project. However, I'm unsure how to properly implement it and configure a CMake file for building my C++ application with this library.

Here are my specific questions:

1. How do I set up a CMake project to include and link the Libcamera library for use in my C++ code on the Raspberry Pi 5?
2. What are the essential components or modules of Libcamera that I need to focus on for integrating a global shutter camera into my project?
3. Could you provide a basic example of a CMakeLists.txt file that correctly includes the Libcamera library and a simple C++ example that demonstrates initializing the library and capturing an image or video stream?

I'm seeking guidance on the initial steps to integrate Libcamera into my C++ project, including setting up the CMake environment, and how to begin utilizing the Libcamera API for camera operations. Any examples, documentation references, or advice on best practices for this setup would be incredibly helpful. Thank you in advance for your support!